# how to make a hyperlink according to incoming data in html?

Tags: python, html, flask, hyperlink

i am working in flask, making a web application. i need to create link after adding an attribute on end of it. i am unable to do so in html.
code is given below

```
{% for result in comments %}
<tr class="bg-info">
  <td><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/"> {{result.complete_title.episode_title}} </td>
  <td> {{result.media_type}} </td>
  <td> {{result.service}} </td>
</tr>
{%endfor %}
```

here i have attribute **result.pid** and link that i want to add at href will be "http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes"+result.pid
i don't knwo how to do it with flask. Any ideas?

Comment: `href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/{{result.pid}}"`?

Comment: thanks mate! you made my life. It is working.

Comment: You should read up on the Jinja templates that you're using - start with e.g. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/templates/

Answer (score 0):

youre not closing your anchor tag, also try attaching the variable that you want to the *href* of the anchor tag as I did below

try

```
<td><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/{{result.complete_title.episode_title}}">LINK TO THE WEBSITE</a>  </td>
```

Comment: He may not be closing the tag but there's more to it that you've fixed here, try to write everything that you've done.